# MySQL sort by most comments

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am learning how to use JOINS. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
So I want to sort my entries by the most comments. This is how I thought I would do.

```
    SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.comment) AS comments_count
    FROM entries a
    LEFT JOIN comments b
    ON a.id = b.entry_id
    ORDER BY comments_count DESC
    LIMIT 6
```

This is obviously the wrong way, any help?
I have a table with comments storing which entry the comment should go to with the row name "entry_id". On the entries table I have the entries with id as the one who is paring up with comments.entry_id.

Edit: I also only get out 1 results by doing this query. Not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `GROUP BY` to get the number of comments for each entry and after that you can sort it.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.*, 
    COUNT(b.comment) AS comments_count
FROM 
    entries a
LEFT JOIN comments b
    ON a.id = b.entry_id
GROUP BY
    a.id
ORDER BY 
    comments_count DESC
```

**NOTE:** when using aggregate functions like `count` without `group by` it will always retun you one row.

Comment: Wow. you just solved this in seconds. Genius! Thank you. Seems like group by is important then. I should read up on this method more.

Comment: I'm glad i could help :) you can start by reading this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html